# How to avoid 'Fatal error for class not found' while running php bin/magento setup:di:compile command

Tags: magento2, plugin

I have created a Payment Gateway plugin for Magento. The PSP is Payrexx.
This  Payment Module extension is created on Magento 2. Within the modules, we have used the external third party PHP library. 
For Manual installation, we are running the following command

```
 php bin/magento module:enable Payrexx_PaymentGateway
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

But the issue is:

" php bin/magento setup:di:compile " 
While running this command we are getting fatal error for class not found, though this command is absolutely necessary to run  our modules.

Comment: please detail your answer with complete error and which lib you used

Comment: It seems like the third party library is missing under lib folder , but providing more details about the error can help to understand this issue

Comment: Thanks Murtuza and Pravin  I shall update more details soon.

Comment: Hi Murtuza and Pravin   Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Murtuza Zabuawala @  Pravin , Thanks for your response.  We have used the third-party library "Payrexx" (https://www.payrexx.com/en/home/) within the module under the lib folder. 

For manual installation, we have used the command "php bin/magento setup:di:compile" in root, We are getting the fatal error for class not found in the included third-party library. 

How to implement the third-party library without any error? Is necessary to run the command "php bin/magento setup:di:compile"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As its open source extension I spent some time to investigate this ,

What I found out is that to run this extension You need to install this following lib.

https://github.com/payrexx/payrexx-php

Comment: Yes Murtuza we need to install the https://github.com/payrexx/payrexx-php  in our extension

Comment: @Sharmistha if my answer solved your concern then mark as accepted , so other user take benifit

Comment: @Sharmistha on the left hand side you will see right tick mark(✔️) , click on that mark so others can wasily see those and its a practice in stackexchange when you accept answer then you click that right mark(✔️)